# How to detect jQuery UI autocompleted field has changed not from list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an simple input text filed with jquery autocomplete function. I have some selectable items and I chose one when the autocomplete setting up the "pid" named field too. After this I change manually  the name of item. This will be a new one, what I need to save into the database. Can I detect somehow the input text field is changed?

I want to set to empty the "pid" named filed.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="pid" id="pid">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#name')).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
         $.ajax({
              url:myurl,
              data:mydata,
              type:'get',
              success: function(data) {
                  response(data.mydat);
              },
              error: function(e,f,g) {
              }
         });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#pid').val( ui.item.id );
        $('#name').val( ui.item.name );
    }
});
```

So can I detect somehow the #name is changed, but not from autocomplete list?

Comment: Your question is unclear....try to be more specific..what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code added in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/257/). It will alert to update database, if name is changed and not equal to one set by autocomplete.

Example code below:

```
    var source  = [ ];
    var mapping = { };
    var trackName;    
    for(var i = 0; i <compName .length; ++i) {
        source.push(compName [i].id);
        mapping[compName[i].id] = compName[i].value;
    }    
    $("#compID").autocomplete({
        source: source,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {   $("#compName").val(mapping[ui.item.value]); 
         trackName = mapping[ui.item.value];
        } 
    });    
    $("#compName").change(function() {
     if($("#compName").val() != trackName)
     {
      alert('Name is changed, Fire ajax and update DB');
     }
    });
```